# Recursive parser treating a '*' as if it was '+'

Tags: scala, parsing

I'm trying to write a Scala recursive parser that utilizes RegEx to parse a simple grammar. Using this code, it works fine if the input in `main` contains only constants and variables with the plus (+) operator but if it contains a multiplying operator (*) it treats it as if it was a plus (+) operator and I'm really unsure what I'm missing. Below is my code:

```
import scala.util.matching.Regex

// S -> E$
// E -> T E2
// E2 -> + E
// E2 -> NIL
// T -> Terminal T2
// T2 -> * T
// T2 -> NIL
// Terminal -> Const
// Terminal -> Val

abstract class S {
  def eval(env: Main.Environment): Int
}

abstract class Terminal extends S

case class E(left: T, right: Option[E2]) extends S {
  def eval(env: Main.Environment): Int = {
    val a1: Int = left match {
      case a: T => left.eval(env)
    }
    right match {
      case Some(r) => a1 + r.eval(env)
      case None => a1
    }
  }
}

case class E2(left: E) extends S {
  def eval(env: Main.Environment): Int = left.eval(env)
}

case class T(left: Terminal, right: Option[T2]) extends S {
  def eval(env: Main.Environment): Int = {
    val a2: Int = left match {
      case v: Var => v.eval(env)
      case c: Const => c.eval(env)
    }
    right match {
      case Some(r) => a2 + r.eval(env)
      case None => a2
    }
  }
}

case class T2(left: T) extends S {
  def eval(env: Main.Environment): Int = left.eval(env)
}

case class Var(n: String) extends Terminal {
  def eval(env: Main.Environment): Int = env(n)
}

case class Const(v: Int) extends Terminal {
  def eval(env: Main.Environment): Int = v
}

class RecursiveDescent(input:String) {
  val constregex: Regex = "^[0-9]+".r
  val varregex: Regex = "^[A-Za-z]+".r

  var index = 0

  def parseS(): S = parseE()

  def parseE(): E = E(parseT(), parseE2())

  def parseE2(): Option[E2] = {
    if (index < input.length && input(index) == '+') {
      index+=1; // Advance past +
      Some(E2(parseE()))
    }
    else None
  }

  def parseT(): T = T(parseTerminal(), parseT2())

  def parseT2(): Option[T2] = {
    if (index < input.length && input(index) == '*') {
      index+=1; // Advance past *
      Some(T2(parseT()))
    }
    else None
  }

  def parseTerminal(): Terminal = {
    // Get the unparsed part of the string.
    val currStr = input.substring(index)

    // Get either the const or var which is there.
    val consts = constregex.findAllIn(currStr)
    if (consts.hasNext){
      val const: String = consts.next()
      index += const.length()
      Const(const.toInt)
    }
    else {
      val vars = varregex.findAllIn(currStr)
      val varname = vars.next()
      index += varname.length()
      Var(varname)
    }
  }
}

object Main {
  type Environment = String => Int
  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    val env: Environment = {
      case "x" => 5
      case "y" => 7
    }

    val rd = new RecursiveDescent("x*y")
    val exp2rd:S = rd.parseE()
    println(exp2rd)
    println(exp2rd.eval(env))
  }
}
```

As in the `main` function I'm having `x = 5` and `y = 7` and request the program to parse `x*y`, that the printed answer should be `35` instead of `12`. I think it has something to do with the `case class E` function but not sure what is wrong there.

Comment: Have You heard about http://www.lihaoyi.com/fastparse? It is great project and simplifies writing parsers. Here is example of such simple math parser: https://scalafiddle.io/sf/cZdDHUb/1

Comment: Scala has a built-in parser combinators package for this (`scala.util.parsing`) which is worth investigating.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found what I did wrong. Under the function `case class T` the `right match` is supposed to be `a2 * r.eval(env)` instead of `a2 + r.eval(env)` and I didn't recognized it since I literally copy and paste that part from `case class E` and do a slight refactor.